# No logro resolver el siguiente programa: Es de 3 listas

Tags: python

La primera lista es de números generados al azar, la segunda lista muestra cuántos dígitos tiene cada elemento de la lista, y la ultima lista tiene que mostrar cuantas veces se repitió un numero de la segunda lista
Un ejemplo:

```
L1=[6,673,89,90,90]
L2=[1,3,2,2,2]
L3=[1,1,3]
```

L1 se genera al azar lista 2 detecta cuantos dígitos tiene cada elemento de la lista 1 y la lista 3 muestra cuántas veces se repito n numero de la lista 3
la lista 1 y  2 funcionan el problema es la lista 3 que muestra cuantas veces se repito n pero no de manera abreviada, si no hace todo el recorrido

CÓDIGO:

```
import random
l1=[]
l2=[]
l3=[]
for x in range(10):
    r=random.randint(1,9999)
    l1.append(r)
    c=len(str(l1[x]))
    l2.append(c)
for x in l2:
    a=l2.count(x)
    l3.append(a)        
print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
l1=[]
l2=[]
l3=[]
l4=[]
for x in range(10):
    r=random.randint(1,9999)
    l1.append(r)
    c=len(str(l1[x]))
    l2.append(c)
for x in l2:
    if x not in l4:
        a=l2.count(x)
        l3.append(a)
        l4.append(x)        
print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)
```

Está muy bien tu código. Solo te faltaba añadir una lista auxiliar en la que ir almacenando los valores mostrados para que solo aparezcan una vez.

Para ello, puedes crear la lista `l4` y comprobar con `if x not in l4:` que lo que vas a imprimir no ha sido mostrado previamente. En `l4` vas añadiendo los valores mostrados con `l4.append(x)`.

El resultado es:

```
[4641, 8165, 4186, 3064, 7768, 4203, 641, 7305, 8036, 8841]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4]
[9, 1]
```

Comment: Gracias! no entendia bien como arreglar ese ejercicio :D